# Broken links to appendix with jmlr2e.sty package

Tags: hyperref, packages, links, appendix

I am writing a LaTex document using the [jmlr2e.sty package](http://www.jmlr.org/format/format.html).

In the main text I want to refer to the Appendix using links. On the pdf when I click on the links they redirect me to the current section instead of redirecting me to the appendix.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{jmlr2e}
\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\editor{John}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
     See Appendix~\ref{app:appendix} for more details.
\newpage

\appendix

\section{The Details}
\label{app:appendix}
     Here are more details

\end{document}
```

When I click on `A` on the pdf document I am redirected to the section Introduction instead of the Appendix.

I am quite lost in the `jmlr2e.sty` file that I am not supposed to modify. Here is what I read on the appendix:

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \def\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\def\section{\@ifnextchar*{\@startsiction{section}{1}{\z@}{-0.24in}{0.10in}%
         {\large\bf\raggedright}}%
 {\@startsiction{section}{1}{\z@}{-0.24in}{0.10in}
         {\large\bf\raggedright Appendix\ }}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the following line before the `\appendix` instruction.

```
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{A\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: Add it to the preamble instead. Littering these commands throughout your article gives it a bad structure. You seem to be able to get away with just `\renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection}`. The issue is the hyperref anchor nit being unique as it takes the number value of the section counter, and thus there are now two labelled `1`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the matter. However putting this line in the preamble does not work...

Comment: It did for me on your MWE

Comment: Hmm that's strange, it does not work on the MWE for me...

Comment: You should of course not be using  `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{A\arabic{section}}` but something similar to `\renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection}`, adding your version to the preamble does not make it unique.